# Quickblox iOS: connecting to QBChat after app was in background error

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

Currently using `Quickblox iOS SDK` v2.4.6, but had this issue before on earlier versions.

Connecting to QBChat:

```
[[QBChat instance] connectWithUser:self.qbUserForChatLogin];
```

User for connection:

```
-(QBUUser *)qbUserForChatLogin
{    
    QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
    user.ID = ... //setting correct ID here
    user.password = [QBSession currentSession].sessionDetails.token;
    return user;
}
```

I'm using facebook authentication, so setting session token as password as told here: http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Login_.2F_ID

So after app launch and authorization connecting to QBChat works fine, and even after app goes background and back to foreground in like tens of minutes app still connects to QBChat. But after long enough time (maybe few hours) when app comes back to foreground and trying to connect to QBChat I receive

`-(void)chatDidNotConnectWithError:(NSError *)error`

with error code `401` and description `Password not verified`.

I also checking if session token is valid:

```
[QBSession currentSession].tokenValid
```

and it is valid.

So how do I handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentations:](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios) 
By default iOS SDK doesn't reconnect automatically when connection to server is lost. You have to manage this manually.

But there is a way to enable automatic reconnection:

```
[QBSettings setAutoReconnectEnabled:YES];
```

So use this code snippet to support auto reconnection.